# why are there 2 different variables in this linq statement?

Tags: c#, linq, variables, lambda

why are there 2 different variables ( **r** and **x**) in the linq statement below?

```
var letters = new Dictionary<int, string>();
letters.Add(1, "a");
letters.Add(2, "b");
letters.Add(3, "c");
letters.Add(4, "d");
letters.Add(5, "b");
....

 Dictionary<string,List<int>> mydict  = 
               letters.GroupBy(r=> r.Value)
              .ToDictionary(x=> x.Key, x=> x.Select(r=> r.Key).ToList());
```

and why do "GroupBy" and "Select" clauses use the same variable (**r**) ?

Answer (score 4):

A lambda expression can be thought of as a type of in-line function.

You could rewrite your code as the following (if you ignore the Expression Tree side of Linq).

```
Dictionary<string,List<int>> mydict  = 
           letters.GroupBy(Grouping)
          .ToDictionary(KeySelector, ValueSelector);

public string Grouping(KeyValuePair<int, string> r)
{
    return r.Value;
}

public string KeySelector(IGrouping<string, KeyValuePair<int, string>> x)
{
    return x.Key;
}

public List<int> ValueSelector(IGrouping<string, KeyValuePair<int, string>> x)
{
    return x.Select(r => r.Key).ToList();
}
```

This might help in showing you how each `x` is a difference scope. Just like each function has a different scope for their parameters.

However in the last function. You will see there is an inner-scoped function, for the select. This needs to be a different named parameter, to avoid clashing with the outter `x`. Hence it needs to be `r`.

Finally. Don't expand out these lambdas un-neccessarily in Linq queries. As I mentioned before, there is something called `Expression Trees`. These named functions can't be used to build expression trees, which is how Linq can be used to build SQL queries.

Comment: Aron, so, we cant replace the last `r=>r` with `x=>x`. cause xs will overlap. right?

Comment: Yes. Technically, its because there already exists a variable/parameter called `x` in scope. So you would be defining another variable/parameter with the same name. In *some* cases, its legal to do so, but its NEVER a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

**r** and **x** are not the variables

These are the alias of the element in *Dictionary*

This approach is used **lambda expression** to point to any/all element in generics.

to know more [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)